# Can I improve python runtime by compiling?

Tags: python, compilation, runtime, scientific-computing

I'm writing a small toy simulation in python. Granted, this simulations are slow. To my understanding, the major reason that python codes are slow is the fact that python is in interpreted language. I don't want to give up python since the clear syntax and the available library cut the writing time significantly. So is there a simple way for me to "compile" my python code?

**Edit**

I answer some questions:
Yes, I'm using numpy. It greatly simplify the code and I don't think I can improve performance writing the functions on my own. I use numpy for all my lists and and I add all of the beads together. Namely. I invoke

```
pos += V*dt + forces*0.5*dt**2
```

where ''pos'', 'V', and 'forces' are all `np.array` of `(2000,3)` dimensions. 
I'm quite certain that the slow part in the forces calculation. This is logical as I have to iterate over all my particles and check their position. For my real project (Ph.D. stuff) I have code of about roughly the same level of complexity, and I know that this is the expensive stuff.

Comment: Yes its possible to compile, http://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html.

Comment: Are you using `numpy` for your calculations? You could also try [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) which is a faster python interpreter than the "default" one written in C.

Comment: Also depending on the simulation it may be amenable to using numpy.

Comment: Also, different ways of writing python can have large performance differences. There are also C extensions that can help in some areas. Can you show us some code?

Comment: @Gjordis this does not really make sense. `py_compile` only manually does what every python-invocation does with source code - namely byte-compiling it.

Comment: @sebastian, yes it does. but if you use like embedded systems etc. this saves startuptime, if you have modules already in byteform. It doesn't improve performance in any other way. I answered the question, is it possible to compile python. This is why I posted an comment, not an answer.

Comment: Have you profiled your application to figure out where its actually slow? Just "compiling it" may not solve your problem. If its stuck on I/O running it on the fastest compiled language won't help.

Comment: Definitely profile your code. For the snippet you've shown I would consider trying https://github.com/pydata/numexpr

Comment: Doing a lot of calculations is slow in every language ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a slightly odd language in that it is both interpreted and compiled. Well sort of. When you run it is compiled to ".pyc" bytecode - so we can quickly get bogged down in semantic details here. Hell I don't even know if what I just said is strictly accurate. But at the end of the day you want to speed things up so...

1. First, use [the profiler](http://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and [timeit](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to work out where all the time is going
2. Second, rewrite your pure python code to improve the slow bits you've discovered
3. Third, see how it goes when [optimised](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-OO)
4. Now, depends on your scenario, but seriously think "Can I run it on a bigger CPU/memory"
5. Ok, try [rewriting those slow sections in C++](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/extending.html)
6. Screw it, write it all in C++

If you get so far as the last option I dare say you're screwed and the savings aren't going to be significant.

Comment: Nothing "odd" about Python -- that's how many if not most programming languages work: source code gets parsed and transformed into bytecode which is then executed... sometimes the bytecode is machine specific in which case we call the result a *native binary*, sometimes the result requires a bytecode interpreter better known as a *virtual machine*.

Comment: Well, profiling my code, I learn that I call ``numpy.zeros`` sh*$load of times (actual ``cProfile`` output) with ``cumtime`` of 5.69 seconds(?) out of total of 78.108 seconds. So if there anything to reduce, for now, it is there. Can I improve it by doing this manually?  I don't think so since the ''percall'' value is 0

Answer (score 3):

If none of the solutions in the comment suffice, you can also take a look at cython.
For a quick tutorial & example check:

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Used at the correct spots (e.g. around frequently called functions) it can easily speed things up by a factor of 10 - 100.